# Is this plant some kind of Poppy?

Tags: houseplants, identification, poppy

I'll start by saying I'm by no means a gardener and I usually kill anything that's green and lives in a pot, however I'd like to say this one is doing well, judging by its height. It no doubt needs to be repotted very soon, I can see blotches appearing on the leaves.

My girlfriend and I are debating the identity of this plant. We bought it a while back and subsequently lost the label with the name on it.

We seem to have some lingering memory that it might be some kind of Poppy, but we are unsure - and Googling Poppies turns up plants that look *nothing* like this one here.

It also seems to be bearing fruit that look a little like small peppers or chillies to me, but again, I'm not a botanist.

So, what kind of plant is this?

Here are some pictures (click on each for a larger image)

[image: Unidentified Plant 1]
[image: Unidentified Plant 2]
[image: Unidentified Plant 3]

---

**Update:**

The flowers eventually came through, and they look exactly like the plant Shanna mentioned in her answer. I always thought poppies were red :)

[image: Poppy!]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like Papaver somniferum, the opium poppy, and as the others answered, those are flower buds. Your plants look very lush!

Answer (score 13):

It looks pretty much like a poppy. Once those flower buds open (which looks like will be happening soon), you can get a definite answer. The flower is usually much more definitive than the vegetative growth.

[image]
<sub>Source: Wikimedia commons</sub>

Answer (score 8):

It looks like some sort of poppy-like thing to me.   If I am correct, those are not fruit, they are flower buds.